# View does not manage to observe all property changes in ViewModel

Tags: wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

1. Case:

There is a View which contains CustomRichTextBox.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty NewOutputLogItemProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("NewOutputLogItem",
            typeof(OutputLog ), typeof(CustomRichTextBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, OnNewOutputLogAdded));

public OutputLog NewOutputLogItem
{
    get { return (OutputLog )GetValue(NewOutputLogItemProperty ); }

    set { SetValue(NewOutputLogItemProperty , value); }
}

private static void OnNewOutputLogAdded(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
{
    var richBox = (CustomRichTextBox)obj;

    var outputLog = (OutputLog )args.NewValue;

    richBox.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() =>
    {
        var mainParagraph = richBox.Document.Blocks.FirstBlock as Paragraph;

        if (mainParagraph != null)
        {         

                mainParagraph.Inlines.AddRange(outputLog.GetInlines());
        }
    }));
}
```

There is also ViewModel which via MVVM light Messenger receives messages and set that property View binds to.

```
public void ProcessNotificationMessage(OutputLog message)
{        
    NewOutputLog = message;          
}
```

Unfortunately I observed that some messages are not depicted if ProcessNotificationMessage works too fast and as a result View misses single messages.

Do you have any idea how to ensure it to work properly?